# ran 0 tests in 0.000s - while executing Python-unittest with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

```
    import unittest
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class loginAvaliador(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/r13/dev/chromedriver')

def login_avaliador(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://d3dyod5mwyu6xk.cloudfront.net/")
    assert "FGV" in driver.title
    cpf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="CPF"]')
    cpf.send_keys("27922797885")
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="SENHA"]')
    password.send_keys("enccejaregular")
    login = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
    login.click()
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

when i try to run this test script it returns "ran 0 tests in 0.000s" why this is happening? i'm new to python and writting this test scripts so i can't find the error

Answer (score 0):

With the unittest module, you need to use their built in assertion methods. Instead of  just writing

```
assert a not in b
```

you write

```
self.assertNotIn("No results found.",driver.page_source)
```

for example. For a list of all the assert methods look here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase

Comment: I understand, but I still have the same problem as before

Answer (score 0):

While working through Python's **unittest** module with *Selenium* you have to consider a few facts as follows :

- You need to take care of the indents. Indentation for `class` and `test_method` are different.
- While you define the `@Tests` name the tests starting with **test** e.g.

  ```
  def test_login_avaliador(self):
  ```
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Here is your own code with the required minor modifications :

  ```
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  class loginAvaliador(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

      def test_login_avaliador(self):
          driver = self.driver
          driver.get("http://d3dyod5mwyu6xk.cloudfront.net/")
          assert "FGV" in driver.title
          cpf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="CPF"]')
          cpf.send_keys("27922797885")
          password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="SENHA"]')
          password.send_keys("enccejaregular")
          login = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
          login.click()
          assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- Execution Result:

  ```
  C:\path\to\PyPrograms>python -m unittest 52560471_unittest.py

  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12022/devtools/browser/078fc4e9-3ca6-4bbb-b318-0b8f04318d32
  .
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 1 test in 40.796s

  OK
  ```

Comment: if you only have a single driver instance, close() will act the same as quit()